Monotone convergence theorem - proof

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and
$\{f_n(x)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on
$X$ such that $0\leq f_1(x)\leq f_2(x)\leq \dots$ ($\mu-a.e.$).
Let $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ as $n\to \infty$ ($\mu-a.e.$). Then $$\lim
_{n\to \infty}\int_{X}f_n(x)d\mu=\int_{X}f(x)d\mu.$$

If we consider $h\geq0$ a simple function such that $h\leq f$; $\epsilon >0$ then we could define the following sets:
$$X_n := \{x \in X \mid f_n(x) \geq (1-\epsilon)h(x)\}$$ and we could finally define $\tilde{X}= \cup_{n\geq1}X_n$ with $\mu(\tilde{X^C})=0$ but I didn't understand where we're using $\epsilon$ in first place and as we have pointwise convergence of $(f_n)_{(n \in \mathbb{N})}$, could it happen that $\sup||f_n-f||\geq \epsilon_{0}$ for some $\epsilon_0 > 0$, what is the motivation behind shifting from $h(x)$ to $(1-\epsilon)h(x)$?

What is your question?

The motivation of the factor $1-\epsilon$ comes from the fact that $f_n$ might be strictly smaller than $h$ everywhere, e.g. $f_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$ and $f=h=1$. In this case the sets $X_n$ are empty. Intuitively, your sequence doesn't "beat" every simple approximation of your function $f$, it "beats" every rescaling of the simple approximation (after removing a null set). The inequality ou have stated cannot happen then because if $h$ is close to your function $f$ by less than $\epsilon_0$ in the $L^1$-norm, the fact that $\bigcup X_n$ is almost the entire space for every $\epsilon>0$ (up to measure zero) tells you that at least in a finite measure space, your sequence of functions is close enough to the approximating function to be a good approximation by itself (I assume you mean $L^1$-norm). This proof requires adaptation for $\sigma$-finite measure spaces.
